# Why $\pi$ appears in Dirac?

Tags: approximation, distribution-theory

"With hands", what is the reason why $\pi$ appears in this result :

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}=\pi\delta(x)$

Comment: Because $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\pi.$$

Comment: Or this one: [What's the deal with this $\frac1\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3102893/42969)

Comment: Thank you @Martin R. The link is very technical and does not give a justification "with hands" : it just show the mathemaical explanation : so $\pi$ appears from nowhere, from mathematics. The answer from Dldier_ explains the principle. Thanks

Comment: Er...no it doesn't, it is a very vague nod to the first link above ( and the second comment does a better job too). The answer you like below has the $\pi$ appearing from nowhere. Just sayin'

Answer (score 2):

Because the left hand side is the derivative of $\text{arctan}$ (by rescaling), so it has to do with trigonometry and $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you know that 
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}\to C\delta, $$
and you want to compute $C$. Taking integrals termwise, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}\, dx\to C, $$
and the change of variable $y=\epsilon x$ shows that the left-hand side equals 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\pi.$$